# Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: 'File res/drawable/abc_ic_clear_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f07001d'

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin (and Xamarin.Forms if they are different). I placed some **Entries** on page. As soon as I tap one on real **Android 4.4** device or inside **4.4 emulator**, the application crash with error:

```
Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: 'File res/drawable/abc_ic_clear_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f07001d'
```

No crash on **Android 6.0** real device and **9.0 emulator**. I think crash somehow related with `ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing"`, because there is **clear** in missing XML.

```
<Entry Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing" Keyboard="Numeric" Text="15" TextChanged="PriceEntry_TextChanged" />
<Entry Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing" Keyboard="Numeric" Text="0" TextChanged="AmountEntry_TextChanged" />
```

This is how I define **Entries** in XAML. I want my app to specifically work under **Android 4.4**. What to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this issue.

[image]

To fix this, please try adding the code below into your MainActivity.cs OnCreate method:

```
    Android.Support.V7.App.AppCompatDelegate.CompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled = true;
```

[image]

Let me know if you have any other questions or concerns.